# Perl SOAP::Lite and Service Description to Request Object

Tags: perl, wsdl, soaplite

I'm using Perl's `SOAP::Lite` to access a remote web service defined by a WSDL. That means I have:

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use SOAP::Lite +trace => 'debug';

my $service = SOAP::Lite->service('http://path/wsdl');
```

Ok so far. Problem is that I need access to the `HTTP::Request` object to send along custom HTTP request headers (and I'm not talking about authentication headers). It looks like I can access the request object after doing a successful call:

```
my $result = $service->getClient('parameters');
print Dumper($service->transport->http_request);
```

That'll give me the correct `HTTP::Request` object:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
             '_content' => '',
             '_uri' => undef,
             '_headers' => bless( {}, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
             '_method' => undef
           }, 'HTTP::Request' );
```

If I try to access the request object before doing an autoDispatch (the `$service->getClient` part), the transport object is empty and I have no way of modifying the request. It seems like everything would work fine if I were going the `SOAP::Lite->proxy` way -- but that defeats the helpfulness of having a pre-defined service definition.

Any ideas how I'm suppose to access the request object from a service definition without first having to make a call? Chicken and egg problem really...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*What I'm trying to accomplish is populating the transport before doing a service call.*

And you do **exactly that** by adding the appropriate handler, because the transport is not empty

Answer (score 0):

Add a handler to the transport, see LWP::Debug for example, see LWP::UserAgent for documentation, or perlmonks.org/?node_id=904166 for example

Comment: Unfortunately, the transport is empty until I do a call. If I had access to the transport, I'd have access to the headers. What I'm trying to accomplish is populating the transport before doing a service call.